# Using 'window' functions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to process rows of a data-frame in order, but need to look-back for certain rows.  Here is an approximate example:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data_frame(trial = rep(c("A","a","b","B","x","y"),2))
d <- d %>%
  mutate(cond = rep('', n()), num = as.integer(rep(0,n())))

for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
  if(d$trial[i] == "A"){
  d$num[i] <- 0
  d$cond[i] <- "A"
  }
else if(d$trial[i] == "B"){
  d$num[i] <- 0
  d$cond[i] <- "B"
  }
else{
  d$num[i] <- d$num[i-1] +1
  d$cond[i] <- d$cond[i-1]
  }
}
```

The resulting data-frame looks like

```
> d
Source: local data frame [12 x 3]

    trial cond num
 1      A    A   0
 2      a    A   1
 3      b    A   2
 4      B    B   0
 5      x    B   1
 6      y    B   2
 7      A    A   0
 8      a    A   1
 9      b    A   2
10      B    B   0
11      x    B   1
12      y    B   2
```

What is the proper way of doing this using `dplyr`?

Comment: Is there any way to replicate `na.locf()` in `dplyr`??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dlpyr`-only solution:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(i=cumsum(trial %in% c('A','B'))) %>% 
  mutate(cond=trial[1],num=seq(n())-1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-i)

#    trial cond num
# 1      A    A   0
# 2      a    A   1
# 3      b    A   2
# 4      B    B   0
# 5      x    B   1
# 6      y    B   2
# 7      A    A   0
# 8      a    A   1
# 9      b    A   2
# 10     B    B   0
# 11     x    B   1
# 12     y    B   2
```

Comment: wonderful. `relid` is implemented using `cumsum()`.  Does `trial[1]` mean the first observation within the by group (i)?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
d %>% 
  mutate(cond = zoo::na.locf(ifelse(trial=="A"|trial=="B", trial, NA))) %>%
  group_by(id=rep(1:length(rle(cond)$values), rle(cond)$lengths)) %>% 
  mutate(num = 0:(n()-1))  %>% ungroup %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. The first thing was to add A or B in `cond` using `ifelse`. Then, I employed `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package in order to fill NA with A or B. I wanted to assign a temporary group ID before I took care of `num`. I borrowed `rleid()` in the `data.table` package. Grouping the data with the temporary group ID (i.e., `foo`), I used `row_number()` which is one of the window functions in the `dplyr` package. Note that I tried to remove `foo` doing `select(-foo)`. But, the column wanted to stay. I think this is probably something to do with compatibility of the function.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

d <- data_frame(trial = rep(c("A","a","b","B","x","y"),2))

mutate(d, cond = ifelse(trial == "A" | trial == "B", trial, NA),
          cond = na.locf(cond),
          foo = rleid(cond)) %>%
group_by(foo) %>%
mutate(num = row_number() - 1)

#   trial cond foo num
#1      A    A   1   0
#2      a    A   1   1
#3      b    A   1   2
#4      B    B   2   0
#5      x    B   2   1
#6      y    B   2   2
#7      A    A   3   0
#8      a    A   3   1
#9      b    A   3   2
#10     B    B   4   0
#11     x    B   4   1
#12     y    B   4   2
```

Comment: I loaded `data.table` library. but, could not find the function `rleid`.  Khashaa's code seems to accomplish the same task using `rle`.  I wonder, if there is a purrr `dplyr` way of doing this?  thanks.

Comment: @user151410 I think `rleid()` in one of the latest function in `data.table`. If you download the dev version from Github, I am sure you have the function.